# Yesod custom field of type [Double]

Tags: json, forms, field, yesod

I want to create a custom field in Yesod that is a text field with a JSON array of doubles.  However I keep getting type errors. My current attempt is:

```
    doubleListField :: RenderMessage master FormMessage => Field sub master [Double]
    doubleListField = Field
        { fieldParse = parseHelper $ Right . decodeUtf8 . parse json

        , fieldView = \theId name attrs val isReq -> toWidget [hamlet|
        $newline never
    <input id="#{theId}" name="#{name}" *{attrs} type="number" :isReq:required="" value="Hey">
    |]
         }
```

(Correct whitespace found: https://gist.github.com/4394850)

I'm currently failing with:

```
        Couldn't match expected type `Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString'
            with actual type `[Text]
                              -> m0 (Either (SomeMessage master0) (Maybe Text))'
In the second argument of `($)', namely `parseHelper $ Right'
In the `fieldParse' field of a record
In the expression:
  Field
    {fieldParse = parse json $ parseHelper $ Right,
     fieldView = \ theId name attrs val isReq
                   -> toWidget (\ _render_a5Cg -> ...)}
```

fieldView I'll modify and I know how to go about that but I'm flummoxed about how fieldParse should look.  Thanks!

Comment: Could you edit your code snippet to have the correct indentation/whitespace here please?

Comment: Sure I'll give it another go, the linked gist has it correctly though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that your code does not match the error.

The `fieldParse` function should turn the user submitted data into a Haskell structure. As you discovered, there is a `parseHelper` function that simplifies creating the field.

The type of `parseHelper` is essentially `(Text -> Either FormMessage a) -> X`, where `X` is the exact type of `fieldParse`. That is, once you pass one argument to the helper, you get a correct `fieldParse`.

The argument to `parseHelper` should be a function, that recieves a `Text` input and returns `Right [Double]` or `Left FormMessage` if parsing failed.

Depending on what you use to parse the JSON, the function could look like this (assuming existence of a few more helpers that you will most likely have to write):

```
fieldParse = parseHelper $ \text -> case parse json text of
    Right value | isListOfDoubles value -> Right $ extractListOfDoubles value
    _ -> Left "Wrong input"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Been a while since I've played with the code but I'll take another crack after reading this.